# How to backfill a continuous query in InfluxDB?

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I have a DB which has years of stored historical data.
My goal is to re-sample this data in `1m` intervals and save to a different DB.
My understanding is that this is easily achievable with a `continous query`.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_name ON db_2 
BEGIN 
SELECT last(data_point) AS ldp 
INTO db_2.autogen.data_points 
FROM db.autogen.data_points 
WHERE time > now() - 12w AND time < now() - 10w 
GROUP BY time(1m), * 
END
```

The above query works fine without the `WHERE` clause and re-sample from the point of creation - forwards.
I added the `WHERE` clause in order to backfill a specific time period (between 12 and 10 weeks ago), however nothing happened.

From posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517121/best-way-to-test-continuous-queries-before-adding-them-to-production-influxdb) and [that one](https://community.influxdata.com/t/backfilling-a-continuous-query/1960), I understand that backfilling is possible by adding `INTO` and `WHERE` clause, but nothing happens.

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date / Times in CQ's are ignored. CQ's cannot be used for backfill.

However, you can remove the CQ "wrapper" from your query and run it manually; just remember to create the windows.

```
CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_name ON db_2 
BEGIN 
SELECT last(data_point) AS ldp 
INTO db_2.autogen.data_points 
FROM db.autogen.data_points 
GROUP BY time(1m), * 
END
```

Becomes:

```
SELECT last(data_point) AS ldp 
INTO db_2.autogen.data_points 
FROM db.autogen.data_points 
WHERE time > now() - 12w AND time < now() - 10w 
GROUP BY time(1m), *
```